# auto increment foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

- Table 1 - **item**
- Table 2 - **sale** (has an auto increment primary key)
- Table 3 - **sale_item** (primary key of this table is the itemId of table 1 and the auto increment saleID of table two)

How can I update the third table with the auto increment saleID?

My code below is not working.

```
string query1 = "Update item set qty = '" + final + "'where itemId ='" + item + "'";

int rows = db.SaveUpdateDelete(query1);
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
int day = d.Day;
int month = d.Month;
int year = d.Year;

string dt = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;

string query2 = "Insert into sale (empID,date) values ('" + usename + ",'" + dt + "')";
int rows1 = db.SaveUpdateDelete(query2);

string query3 = "Insert into sale_item (itemId, qty, unit_price) values ('" + item + "','" + qty + "','" + price + "'";
int rows2 = db.SaveUpdateDelete(query3);
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: "My code below is not working." please be a little more precise than this.  Exceptions? errors? did your computer implode?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @MongZhu sql syntax isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as insert is done in second table sale, Execute top 1 from sale table
based on id.
Get the sale id from that output, insert into third table. Did execute below code with dummy values and it worked.

```
        var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Update item set qty = '" + 30 + "'where itemId ='" + 1 + "'",conn);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        int day = d.Day;
        int month = d.Month;
        int year = d.Year;

        string dt = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
        string username = "jyothi";
        SqlCommand query2 = new SqlCommand("Insert into sale (empID,date1) values ('" + 22 + "','" + dt + "')",conn);
        query2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int saleid=0;
        SqlCommand query3 = new SqlCommand("select top 1 id from sale order by id desc",conn);
        var dreader = query3.ExecuteReader();
        if (dreader.Read())
        {
            saleid = Convert.ToInt32(dreader[0].ToString());

        }
        dreader.Close();


        SqlCommand query4 = new SqlCommand("Insert into saleitem (saleid,itemId, qty, price) values ('" + saleid + "','" + 1 + "','" + 20 + "','" + 25 + "')", conn);
        query4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: How does it happen at the second instance the program is run, the select top 1 returns the top most record isn't it?

Comment: At second instance also, I believe you are inserting into sale table which has new ID right (auto increment)? if that is not the case you will update the current saleid which you know. That can be given to third query. Please correct me /provide more details.